# ProviderIncompatibleException with Code First Entity Framework - MVC 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to work through one of Pluralsight's MVC 4 tutorials (I want to complete the MVC 4 one before moving on to MVC 5). However, I got a ProviderIncompatibleException when trying to create a local database using Code First Entity Framework. Here is the InnerException:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I've seen other questions on Stack Overflow about similar problems, but none of their solutions work for me, and I don't know what to try next.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=   (LocalDb)\MyInstance;Initial Catalog=aspnet-OdeToFood-20160126155751;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-OdeToFood-20160126155751.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The name of the .mdf file is correct in the connection string. If I look in SQL Server Configuration Manager I can see that all of the following services are running:
**SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)**
**SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)**
**SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)**
**SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)**
**SQL Server Browser**
**SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)**

By typing **sqllocaldb info** into the command line, I can verify that MyInstance exists, and from there I can see that its Version is 11.0.3156.0 and that it is running.

I feel like I must be missing something painfully obvious. Any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC4, perhaps you're also using an old version of EntityFramework that doesn't support localdb?

Try updating EF to a later version.

As an aside, I wouldn't bother with tutorials for old versions of software, they may well be teaching you features which have since become obsolete!